# Compute $\int_n^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{x^n+\sin(nx)}$

Tags: integration

$$\int_n^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{x^n+\sin(nx)}$$

(In terms of $n$)
I've struggled on this for quite some time because it seems to prove impossible to break up that extremely annoying $\sin (nx)$ term. I attempted integration by parts, but to no avail. I really don't know what to do, however.

Comment: MAPLE cannot find the primitive even for $n=1$! :) This is really a tough integral! :) Where did it appear to you? :)

Comment: @H.R. I was trying to modify $\frac{1}{1+x^n}$ to make it more interesting. I found this

Comment: So it just came out of your imaginations! :) This integral is frightening! :)

Comment: Can the downvoters explain themselves? This looks like a reasonable integral in my eyes!

Comment: I think it is due to the lack of motivation for finding this integral! :)

Comment: Since I don't have the rep, are you interested in bountying this? You seem to appreciate it as much as I @H.R.

Comment: Sorry for that! :) I am not really interested to put a bounty on this. :)

Comment: @H.R. It's fine, I can see that

Comment: @H.R., Of course, in the specific case where $n = 1$, the integrand is bounded below by  $\frac{1}{x+1}$, so the definite integral diverges.

Comment: @MarkYasuda: Nice Idea, Maybe you can find a lower bound for the general case and prove that it diverges! :)